# How to use neovim remote feature

Tags: ssh, remote-access, neovim, neovim-plugin

[nvim --remote flag](https://neovim.io/doc/user/remote.html)

1. Does this feature allow me to open a directory/project on a remote machine so that it displays on my local nvim client?
2. If yes, how exactly to achieve this given that I'm using ssh to connect to a remote? I can't understand this from documentation.

I tried mounting the pipe via sshfs on a local machine but that didn't work.

I know `nvim scp://....` exists but I'm looking for a way to open an entire project and `nvim scp` only works for single files. Ideally, I want all my plugins to work, including LSP.

Comment: Just curious, if you already have `sshfs` then why not mount the entire remote directory locally? That should solve your issue.

Comment: @PriteshTupe ssh link is slow and nvim lags every time it has to do IO over the network. I was hoping this --remote is similar to VSCode Remote SSH extension, i.e. it implements buffering.